# Elasticsearch with spark 3.0.0 in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, elasticsearch, hadoop, spark-streaming

Hi i'm trying to intigrate ES with spark job. and i'm getting the below error while i try to push data to ES.
i'm using spark-structured-streaming kafka with java

```
20/07/01 19:00:50 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = eb433c87-501c-4c11-9826-e5cf259bda59, runId = 47071902-430c-4656-9918-25b9695c85bc] terminated with error
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/QueryExecution;Lscala/Function0;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.addBatch(EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.scala:43)
    ...
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:245)
Exception in thread "stream execution thread for [id = eb433c87-501c-4c11-9826-e5cf259bda59, runId = 47071902-430c-4656-9918-25b9695c85bc]" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/QueryExecution;Lscala/Function0;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at ...
org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/QueryExecution;Lscala/Function0;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

below is the code

```
results.select(col("value")).writeStream().outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
                .format("es")
                .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/escheckpoint")
                .start("index/doc").awaitTermination();
```

dependency details

```
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.12', version: '3.0.0'
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.12', version: '3.0.0'
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-streaming_2.12', version: '3.0.0'
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12', version: '3.0.0'
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12', version: '3.0.0'
compile group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch-hadoop', version: '7.8.0'
```

Comment: This error looks like a version incompatibility. `elasticsearch-hadoop` doesn't support scala 2.12 yet https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/pull/1308

Comment: is there any other way to get this working or for now we should fall back to 2.4.6? @eliasah

Comment: It seems for now that you need to go back to 2.4.6. That issue has been hanging there for a while...